# Why is my password list empty but my passwords are still being populated on log-ins?

Tags: password, chromium

The issue has been going on for 2-3 months: my password manager doesn't show my saved passwords anymore.
My passwords are still being populated on log-ins and the offer to save user name and password is still working. The new passwords are being saved and retrieved on log-in.
I just cannot edit or delete my stored passwords.
I am running Chromium Version 86.0.4240.75 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Comment: Have you checked Chromium to see if that's where they're being stored? Settings > Autofill > Passwords and look there. That won't explain why they're stored there - only if that's where they are stored.

Comment: Yes, sadly, it does not show any password saved: " Check passwords: No saved passwords. Chromium can check your passwords when you save them." and "Saved Passwords
Saved passwords will appear here"